# Structural Typing Fails with Unions?

Tags: typescript

I don't quite understand why the following [does not compile](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IPreciousMetal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%22Silver%22%20%7C%20%22Gold%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ICryptoCurrency%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%22Bitcoin%22%20%7C%20%22Litecoin%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Asset%20%3D%20ICryptoCurrency%20%7C%20IPreciousMetal%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20process(assetType%3A%20Asset%5B%22type%22%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20asset%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20assetType%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20processImpl(asset)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20processImpl(asset%3A%20Asset)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(asset.type)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A):

```
interface IPreciousMetal {
    type: "Silver" | "Gold"
}

interface ICryptoCurrency {
    type: "Bitcoin" | "Litecoin"
}

type Asset = ICryptoCurrency | IPreciousMetal;

function process(assetType: Asset["type"]) {
    const asset = { type: assetType };
    processImpl(asset); // Error
}

function processImpl(asset: Asset) {
    console.log(asset.type);
}
```

An argument passed for the parameter `assetType` must be typed such that it is compatible with the `Asset` type. However, when an object is created with with said parameter value, the compiler complains.

Comment: Please check typescript docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of typescript are you on? Typescript 3.5 introduced [smarter union type checking](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/) which should solve your issue. I don't think typescript playground is using that version yet.

Comment: Yeah, this is the right answer.  I wish I could search for all answers I've given that mention [Microsoft/TypeScript#12052](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052) and update them... unfortunately it seems that you can't search for links easily.